# Passing arguments to a thread

Tags: c, pthreads

I have this struct:

```
#define NUM_T 5

typedef struct {
    int j;
    int vetor[BUFFER_SIZE];
} estrutura_main;
```

which I want to pass as argument to threads:

```
estrutura_main structure;
for(i=0;i<NUM_T;i++){
        structure.j=i;
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, sum,(void*)&structure);
}
```

my problem is that when i access `j` in function `sum` it is always 4, and it should be each time a differente number, from 0 to 4. I've tried changing it to

```
typedef struct {
    int j[NUM_T];
    int vetor[BUFFER_SIZE];
} estrutura_main;
```

but I had trouble accessing the position of `j` I wanted in the thread.

How do I solve this?

Comment: You're only allocating storage for a single "structure".  So in your loop you're changing the value of j for that single structure.  Do you want a unique structure per pthread_create?  If so use an array estrutura_main structure[NUM_T];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `&structure` is always the same for your `NUM_T` calls to `pthread_create`.

You may try

```
estrutura_main structure[NUM_T];
for(i=0;i<NUM_T;i++){
    structure[i].j=i;
    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, sum, (void*)&structure[i]);
}
```

then each thread gets a pointer to different instance.